# Вызов метода из контроллера (yii2) с помощью JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

возник вопрос как правильно провернуть вызов функции контроллера со страницы с помощью js.

Код самой страницы:

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

const BASE_URL = "/education/dialogs/add-result-general-test";

$form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(

    ['action' => [BASE_URL . '/apply'],
        'method' => 'post',
        'id' => 'frm00',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute(BASE_URL . '/validation')
    ]);
$checkPath = Url::toRoute(BASE_URL . '/check');
Html::beginForm([BASE_URL . '/check'], 'post',['data-pjax' => '']);
echo $form->field($test, 'test_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\app\modules\education\models\GeneralTest::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),[
    'prompt' => 'Выберите тест',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'onchange'=> "location.href = '. $checkPath . '",
    'name' => 'test_id'
]);
Html::endForm();

\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end();
?>

<div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
<div class="alert alert-error" style="display: none"></div>
```

Код контроллера:

```html
<?php

namespace app\modules\education\controllers\dialogs;

use app\common\BaseController;
use app\modules\education\models\GeneralTestHistory;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Response;

class AddResultGeneralTestController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $assignGeneralTest = new GeneralTestHistory();
        $group = (int)Yii::$app->request->post('id');
        $contactsGroup = $assignGeneralTest->searchContactGroup($group);

        return $this->renderAjax('add-result-general-test', ['test' => $assignGeneralTest,'group' => $group, 'contactsGroup' => $contactsGroup]);
    }

    public function actionCheck(){

        return 'wewe';

    }

    public function actionValidation()
    {
        $test = new GeneralTestHistory();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $test->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return ActiveForm::validate($test);
        }
    }

    public function actionApply()
    {
        
            if(count($arrPost) == $resultSave){
                return ['result' => 'ok', 'message' => "Тест успешно добавлен."];
            } else {
                return ['result' => 'error', 'message' => "Произошла ошибка добавления теста."];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код страницы, где вызывается диалог. окно:

```html
<?php

use yii\grid\GridView;
use app\common\widgets\Dialog;
use app\common\widgets\DialogButton;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

const DIALOG_ADD_RESULT_GENERAL_TEST = 'add-result-general-test';


        echo DialogButton::widget(['title' => 'Добавить групповой тест', 'id' => DIALOG_ADD_RESULT_GENERAL_TEST]);

        echo Dialog::widget([
            'id' => 'dialog-' . DIALOG_ADD_RESULT_GENERAL_TEST,
            'title' => 'Добавить групповой тест',
            'subscribe' => DIALOG_ADD_RESULT_GENERAL_TEST,
            'renderPath' => Url::to(['/education/dialogs/add-result-general-test']),
            'renderParams' => [
                'id' => $model->id

            ],
            'buttons' => [
                DialogButton::widget(['title' => 'Создать', 'id' => DIALOG_ADD_RESULT_GENERAL_TEST . '-apply',
                    'successFunction' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function() { $.pjax.reload(\'#test-zone\' , {timeout : false}); }')
                ])
            ]
        ]);
```

Как правильно повесить событие на **'onchange'** чтобы вызвалась функция **actionCheck()** из контроллера?

заранее спасибо. Убрал часть кода, чтобы было понятней.

Comment: В своём проекте я использую Ajax для этого. В onchange указываю функцию JS, в этой функции выбираю все необходимые данные и отправляю в контроллер. После чего возвращаю результат из контроллера и уже делаю то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправить запрос на controller/check с помощью ajax, получить данные и обработать по усмотрению.